# Failed to load resource: the http://website.azurewebsites.net/signalr/hubs server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, azure, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr-hub

My MVC-5 Azure-hosted Web App (VS 2013 / VB) using SignalR technology seems to not be creating the necessary SignalR/hubs JavaScript page.

Here's all the details:

First, since I believe that Azure will not allow for the creation of the /signalr/hubs source page, I 'stole' a sample hub page from my own SignalR test app. I then added a signalr.js file into Scripts/Custom folder of my web app. Here's the JavaScript file:

```
(function ($, window, undefined) {
    /// <param name="$" type="jQuery" />
    "use strict";

    if (typeof ($.signalR) !== "function") {
        throw new Error("SignalR: SignalR is not loaded. Please ensure jquery.signalR-x.js is referenced before ~/signalr/js.");
    }

    var signalR = $.signalR;

    function makeProxyCallback(hub, callback) {
        return function () {
            // Call the client hub method
            callback.apply(hub, $.makeArray(arguments));
        };
    }

    function registerHubProxies(instance, shouldSubscribe) {
        var key, hub, memberKey, memberValue, subscriptionMethod;

        for (key in instance) {
            if (instance.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                hub = instance[key];

                if (!(hub.hubName)) {
                    // Not a client hub
                    continue;
                }

                if (shouldSubscribe) {
                    // We want to subscribe to the hub events
                    subscriptionMethod = hub.on;
                } else {
                    // We want to unsubscribe from the hub events
                    subscriptionMethod = hub.off;
                }

                // Loop through all members on the hub and find client hub functions to subscribe/unsubscribe
                for (memberKey in hub.client) {
                    if (hub.client.hasOwnProperty(memberKey)) {
                        memberValue = hub.client[memberKey];

                        if (!$.isFunction(memberValue)) {
                            // Not a client hub function
                            continue;
                        }

                        subscriptionMethod.call(hub, memberKey, makeProxyCallback(hub, memberValue));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $.hubConnection.prototype.createHubProxies = function () {
        var proxies = {};
        this.starting(function () {
            // Register the hub proxies as subscribed
            // (instance, shouldSubscribe)
            registerHubProxies(proxies, true);

            this._registerSubscribedHubs();
        }).disconnected(function () {
            // Unsubscribe all hub proxies when we "disconnect".  This is to ensure that we do not re-add functional call backs.
            // (instance, shouldSubscribe)
            registerHubProxies(proxies, false);
        });

        proxies['bpHub'] = this.createHubProxy('bpHub');
        proxies['bpHub'].client = {};
        proxies['bpHub'].server = {
            begin: function () {
                return proxies['bpHub'].invoke.apply(proxies['bpHub'], $.merge(["new"], $.makeArray(arguments)));
            },

            hello: function () {
                return proxies['bpHub'].invoke.apply(proxies['bpHub'], $.merge(["send"], $.makeArray(arguments)));
            },

            helloServer: function () {
                return proxies['bpHub'].invoke.apply(proxies['bpHub'], $.merge(["broadcast"], $.makeArray(arguments)));
            }
        };

        return proxies;
    };

    signalR.hub = $.hubConnection("/signalr", { useDefaultPath: false });
    $.extend(signalR, signalR.hub.createHubProxies());

}(window.jQuery, window));
```

Now, I know that the proxies map to functions in classes that I set up. But I'm not quite sure EXACTLY how to do this, given my very large app. In essence, I've simply added some classes to the project, so they are in the root folder. And then in the Startup.vb file, I do this;

```
Imports Microsoft.Owin
Imports Owin
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR

<Assembly: OwinStartup(GetType(Startup))> 
Public Class Startup
    Public Sub Configuration(app As IAppBuilder)
        Dim cn As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("AzureServiceBus").ConnectionString

        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseServiceBus(cn, "dtxEarth3")

        app.MapSignalR()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then, per the book called *SignalR Real-Time Application Cookbook* by Roberto Vespa, I added the following classes to the root folder of my app;
sigRmb.vb;

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Messaging
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs

<HubName("bpHub")>
Public Class SignalRBackplaneMessageBus
    Inherits ScaleoutMessageBus
    Private ReadOnly _connection As HubConnection
    Private ReadOnly _hub As IHubProxy

    Public Sub New(dependencyResolver As IDependencyResolver, configuration As SignalRBackplaneConfiguration)
        MyBase.New(dependencyResolver, configuration)

        _connection = New HubConnection(configuration.EndpointAddress)

        _hub = _connection.CreateHubProxy("bpHub")

        _hub.[On](Of Byte())("broadcast", Function(m)
                                              Dim message = SignalRBackplaneMessage.FromBytes(m)
                                              OnReceived(0, message.Id, message.ScaleoutMessage)

                                          End Function)

        _connection.Start().Wait()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Function Send(streamIndex As Integer, messages As IList(Of Message)) As Task
        Return Send(messages)
    End Function

    Protected Overrides Function Send(messages As IList(Of Message)) As Task
        If _connection.State <> ConnectionState.Connected Then
            Return Task.FromResult(False)
        End If

        Dim newId = _hub.Invoke(Of Long)("GetId").Result

        Dim data = SignalRBackplaneMessage.ToBytes(newId, messages)

        Return _hub.Invoke("Publish", data)
    End Function
End Class
```

sigRconfig;

```
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Messaging

Public Class SignalRBackplaneConfiguration
    Inherits ScaleoutConfiguration

    Private m_EndpointAddress As String = "Endpoint=sb://dtxdrill-ns.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RigMon100;SharedAccessKey=U7/6C+1y1kExpCMVgG+1tZpvz6um/d4NOiucComR/CU="

    Public Property EndpointAddress() As String
        Get
            Return m_EndpointAddress
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_EndpointAddress = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

sigRbm;

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Messaging

Public Class SignalRBackplaneMessage
    Private m_Id As ULong
    Private m_ScaleoutMessage As ScaleoutMessage

    Public Property Id() As ULong
        Get
            Return m_Id
        End Get
        Private Set(value As ULong)
            m_Id = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property ScaleoutMessage() As ScaleoutMessage
        Get
            Return m_ScaleoutMessage
        End Get
        Private Set(value As ScaleoutMessage)
            m_ScaleoutMessage = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Shared Function ToBytes(id As Long, messages As IList(Of Message)) As Byte()
        If messages Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("messages")
        End If

        Using ms = New MemoryStream()
            Dim binaryWriter = New BinaryWriter(ms)

            Dim scaleoutMessage = New ScaleoutMessage(messages)
            Dim buffer = scaleoutMessage.ToBytes()

            binaryWriter.Write(id)
            binaryWriter.Write(buffer.Length)
            binaryWriter.Write(buffer)

            Return ms.ToArray()
        End Using
    End Function

    Public Shared Function FromBytes(data As Byte()) As SignalRBackplaneMessage
        Using stream = New MemoryStream(data)
            Dim binaryReader = New BinaryReader(stream)
            Dim id = CULng(binaryReader.ReadInt64())
            Dim count = binaryReader.ReadInt32()
            Dim buffer = binaryReader.ReadBytes(count)

            Return New SignalRBackplaneMessage() With { _
                .Id = id, _
                .ScaleoutMessage = ScaleoutMessage.FromBytes(buffer) _
            }
        End Using
    End Function
End Class
```

And this one, called sigR_DependencyResolverExtensions.vb;

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Messaging

Module sigR_DependencyResolverExtensions
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
    Public Sub UseSignalRBackplane(resolver As IDependencyResolver, endpointAddress As String)
        resolver.UseSignalRBackplane(New SignalRBackplaneConfiguration() With { _
            .EndpointAddress = endpointAddress _
        })
    End Sub

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
    Public Sub UseSignalRBackplane(resolver As IDependencyResolver, configuration As SignalRBackplaneConfiguration)
        resolver.Register(GetType(IMessageBus), Function() New SignalRBackplaneMessageBus(resolver, configuration))
    End Sub
End Module
```

And finally, for my view, I have;

```
@Code
    Layout = Nothing
End Code

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Drillers Readout - HTI Job #@ViewBag.JobNumber</title>
    <style>
        #messages li {
            list-style-type: none;
        }
    </style>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/signalR")
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Custom/signalr.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            //var cn = $.hubConnection();
            $.connection.hub.url = "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Custom/signalr.js")";
            var hub = $.connection.bpHub;

            $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
                alert('okay 1');
            })
                .fail(function(e) {
                alert('uh-oh! Connection Error ' + e);
            });

            //var myProxy = cn.createHubProxy('bpHub');

            //var backplane = cn.backplane;

            //myProxy.on('broadcast', function (message) {
            //    $('#messages').prepend($('<li/>').text(message));
            //});

            //cn.start().done(function () {
            //    myProxy.invoke('new');
            //})
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    @*<span id="newTime"></span><br />
    <input type="button" id="btnClick" value="Send Message" /><br />
    <span id="message"></span>*@
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I run it, I get (in Chrome);
http://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/Scripts/Custom/signalr.js/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=...
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404...

I know I've got several things wrong with my code, including setting up the signalr.js file, among other things. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Does your SignalR application work on your local environment? Or it only does not work in Azure side? For general 404 issue, please mark sure your have a call to MapHubs() in Global.asax, and make sure that the Hub route is registered before any other routes in your application. Reference the JavaScript file with @Url.Content, assuming you're using ASP.NET MVC3.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/signalr/hubs")"></script>`

In ASP.NET MVC 4 you can do the following:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>`

See the [SignalR FAQ on GitHub](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Faq)

If this is Azure side issue, Please make sure the SignalR related files has been uploaded to Azure side via KUDU tool. In addition, please also check whether websocket is enabled via [this article](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/deployment/using-signalr-with-azure-web-sites#websocket).

Comment: Websockets are on. I work in production-side only (never local), though I did create a SignalR app that runs a timer on localhost and it works fine. The MapHubs is a remnant of MVC-4; doing app.MapSignalR() in Startup's Configuration Sub is all that's required in MVC-5, I believe, which is what I'm using (see title). I created my own JS hub and put it in Scripts/custom/signalr.js. I'm trying to use ScaleoutMessageBus since my data is on an Azure ServiceBus Queue, but I can't get anything to work.

Comment: Please see my extensive edit, above.  I think it contains all the info relating to signalr and my issues.  Thanks.